# Why is my super().__init__() says i call with too many arguments?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code:

```
import numpy as np
Template_Dict = {"x": ["path/to.data", (2, 1),[0,0,0]], "y": ["path/to.data", (3, 3),[-np.pi/2,0,0]],"z": ["path/to.data", (3, 3),[-np.pi/2,0,0]]}

class A:
    def __init__(self,Templates):
        print("ATemplate",Templates)
        print(self)
        self.Template = Templates[Prob_Type]

class B(A):
    def __init__(self,Templates):
        print("BTemplates",Templates)
        super().__init__(self, Templates)

class C(B):
    def __init__(self,Templates):

        print("CTemplate:",Templates)
        print(self)
        super().__init__(self, Templates)

x=C(Template_Dict)
```

Output:

```
CTemplate: {'x': ['path/to.data', (2, 1), [0, 0, 0]], 'y': ['path/to.data', (3, 3), [-1.5707963267948966, 0, 0]], 'z': ['path/to.data', (3, 3), [-1.5707963267948966, 0, 0]]}
<__main__.C object at 0x7f23f1704430>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "errortest.py", line 22, in <module>
    x=C(Template_Dict)
  File "errortest.py", line 20, in __init__
    super().__init__(self, Templates)
TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

I have no idea why it says i gave 3 positional arguments here. I clearly in class C(B) call super().**init** with 2 arguments: self and Templates.

Comment: Post something that actually runs and reproduces the problem when run. "Kind of" code doesn't cut it if it doesn't reproduce the problem.

Comment: Just ommit `self` from `super().__init__(self, Templates)`. Calling a method implicitly passes `self` as the first argument.

Comment: Sorry, i changed it and i hope it is more clear whats the problem now :-)

Answer (score 2):

Calling instance methods on `super()` is like calling them on the instance itself; `self` is passed implicitly. When you pass it explicitly, it ends up getting passed twice (as if you wrote `A.__init__(self, self, Templates)`). So just use:

```
super().__init__(Templates)
```

without passing `self` explicitly.

Comment: Thanks, this confused me for 2 hours now!